# Sentence Segmentation for Hindi

Tags: nlp

I only found stanza that has sentence segmentation for hindi. All other available tools do word tokenization but not sentence segmentation. Could someone suggest any other available tools for sentence segmentation for Hindi

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that there is no other tool, especially since usually when there are word tokenizers available there are also sentence tokenizers (the two tasks are often performed at the same time).

In case you need to train your own tokenizer, you could use the [Universal Dependencies](https://universaldependencies.org/) Hindi corpus.

Comment: Thanks for the help!